# not run oncreate() ,on tab change in same page, 2nd time

Tags: android

I have 4 tabs in a page view when i click first time on tab it executes it `oncreate()` method of corresponding tab and when i go to other tab on same page and again click on previous clicked tab then its `oncreate()` method not execute why?why it is not work as button click means each time i click its `oncreate()` method run.

***my code for tab activity class is below***

```
  intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, keywordxmlparsing.class);
spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Activity2").setIndicator("keyword/ search...").setContent(intent1);
tabHost.addTab(spec1); 

intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, filter.class);
spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Activity1").setIndicator("filter search").setContent(intent2);
tabHost.addTab(spec2);
intent3 = new Intent().setClass(this, OpeningToday.class);
spec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Activity3").setIndicator("opening today").setContent(intent3);
tabHost.addTab(spec3);
intent4 = new Intent(keywordresulttab.this,Map.class);
spec4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Activity4").setIndicator("Map").setContent(intent4);
tabHost.addTab(spec4);
```

dear if i use

```
    @Override
public void onTabChanged(String label) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(label == "Activity2") {




    }
    try{
    if(label == "Activity4") {
        Intent intent4; 
        intent4 = new Intent(keywordresulttab.this,Map.class);
        startActivity(intent4);
        Log.i("suiuawhd","maps class");




                }
```

*then can i go to other `activity` means using*

```
  intent4 = new Intent(keywordresulttab.this,Map.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
```

we can load again `activity` on tab click??then what to written in place of

```
     tabHost.addTab(spec3);
intent4 = new Intent(keywordresulttab.this,Map.class);
spec4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Activity4").setIndicator("Map").setContent(intent4);
tabHost.addTab(spec4);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tabs that contain activities are implemented by means of ActivityGroup. When someone changes a tab, corresponding activity is created **only** if necessary. When you move to any tab for the second time, the activity is already existing and only its window is shown. 
You should use instead:

```
TabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(TabHost.OnTabChangeListener l)
```

---

TabActivity with separate activities as a content are a little bit tricky so maybe you should consider using Views instead. If not you can use the following code to access all activities from each other:

get instances of content activities from TabActivity:

```
TabActivity.getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(String name)
```

where name is given in newTabSpec() method.

get instance of TabActivity from content activities:

```
FirstTab.getParent()
```

Using these method you can create communication between all activities (using proper casting). For example:

```
public void onTabChanged(String label) {

  if(label.equals("Activity2")) {
      SecondActivity sa = (SecondActivity) getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(label);
      sa.modifySomething();
  }
}
```

---

If you want to change activities under tabs you should use:

```
tabHost.clearAllTabs ()
```

and create all TabSpecs once again.

Comment: Please describe what exactly you want to achieve with the TabHost. Do you want to start different activity for the same tab or change some data inside existing one?

Answer (score 0):

In the android oncreate()  lifecycle called once in life of the  activity  (like constructor), as you press again that time the activity is alive and in memory so it will not call onCreate again.

so you have to implement

```
TabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(TabHost.OnTabChangeListener l).
```

Comment: @ warrior suppose ontabchange() i use to store some values in variables and now on the  same page i click on other tab and want to use previous store values in variables in my next tab class then how to run its oncreate() method 2nd time to show the result based on that values?

Comment: @saurabh when u click on any tab so you are starting a new activity inside the tabhost which is a viewgroup. so your answer is in this page How do I pass data between Activities/Services within a single application? This is frequently asked question refer http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html for your answer.