# on tab change in same page, 2nd time OnCreate() doesn't work

Tags: android, android-tabhost

All the functions are running properly, but only one problem exists that if i record details for a day, and if I switch tab to the history tab to see the new record, the viewlist in the history class should display that record. However the viewlist **doesnot display the lastest record**, and i check the database, the lastest record has been written into database. The only way to see the new record is to close the emulator and restart it.

I  **found the problem** that on startup, the recorder and history tab would both be initialised in OnCreate() method. But after that when I switch between these two tabs, it would not be initialised. Therefore, in the history.class, it would not open the database and read the data. That's the problem. Could somebody please help me, thanks

tab Prototype class

```
package com.example.tabpro;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class TabBar extends TabActivity{

static TabHost tabHost=null;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab);

    tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent recorderIntent = new Intent(TabBar.this, Recorder.class);
    TabSpec recorderTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    recorderTabSpec.setIndicator("Recorder");
    recorderTabSpec.setContent(recorderIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(recorderTabSpec);

    Intent historyIntent = new Intent(TabBar.this,History.class);
    TabSpec historyTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    historyTabSpec.setIndicator("History");
    historyTabSpec.setContent(historyIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(historyTabSpec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


}
public void switchTab(int tab)
{
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);
}
}
```

Recorder.class

```
package com.example.tabpro;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Recorder  extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {


int mYear;
int mMonth;
int mDay;


TextView dateDisplay;
Button pickDateButton;

TextView sbHourValue;
TextView sbMinValue;

int hours;
int mins;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;  



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recorder);

    initialDatePicker();
    initialSeekBar();
    initialSaveButton();

}

public void initialDatePicker()
{
    dateDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay); 
    pickDateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
    pickDateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

      @Override  
      public void onClick(View v) {  
          showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);  
      }  
  });  

  final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();  
  mYear = currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);  
  mMonth = currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);  
  mDay = currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  
  dateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder()  
              .append(mYear).append("-")  
              .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
              .append(mDay)); 


}

public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {  
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {  
        mYear = year;  
        mMonth = monthOfYear;  
        mDay = dayOfMonth;  

        dateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder()  
                    .append(mYear).append("-")  
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")//start from 0
                    .append(mDay));  
    }  
};

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    switch(id)
    {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:  
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,mDateSetListener,mYear, mMonth, mDay); 
    }
    return null;
}



public void initialSeekBar()
{
    SeekBar sbHour = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar_hour);
    sbHour.setMax(23);
    sbHour.setProgress(0);
    sbHour.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    sbHourValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_hour);
    sbHourValue.setText("0"+ " hour(s)");

    SeekBar sbMin = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar_min);
    sbMin.setMax(59);
    sbMin.setProgress(0);
    sbMin.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    sbMinValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView_min);
    sbMinValue.setText("0" + " minute(s)");
}

public void initialSaveButton()
{

    Button saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_save);

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String time;
            String date;

            date = dateDisplay.getText().toString();
            time = hours + " hour(s) " + mins + " minute(s)";


            TabProDB db;
            db = new TabProDB(Recorder.this);
            db.open();

            boolean findSameDay = false;
            Cursor c = db.GetAllRecords();

              if(c!=null)
              {
                  if (c.moveToFirst())
                  {
                    do {
                        String dateToCompare = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabProDB.KEY_DATE));
                        if(dateToCompare.equalsIgnoreCase(date))
                        {
                            findSameDay = true;
                        }
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                  }
              }
            if(findSameDay!=true)
            {
                long id = db.insertRecord(date, time);
                db.close();
                Toast.makeText(Recorder.this, "Record Saved" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(Recorder.this, "You have already recorded the today: " + date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                db.close();
            }
            switchTabInActivity(1);
        }

    });

}

public void switchTabInActivity(int index)
{
    TabBar parentActivity;
    parentActivity = (TabBar)this.getParent();
    parentActivity.switchTab(index);

}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(arg0.getId() == R.id.seekBar_hour){
    // update hour value
    hours = arg1;
    sbHourValue.setText(Integer.toString(arg1)+" hour(s)");

}
else{
    // update minute value
    mins = arg1;
    sbMinValue.setText(Integer.toString(arg1)+" minute(s)");
}       
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

History.class

```
package com.example.tabpro;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class History  extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {


int getdbID;
String Date;
String Time;
ListView date_time_ListView;
ArrayList<String> listItems = null;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.history);

    date_time_ListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    TabProDB db = new TabProDB(this);

        try{
            listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.GetAllRecords();
            if(c!=null)
            {
                if (c.moveToFirst())
                {
                   do{
                        String date1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabProDB.KEY_DATE) );
                        String time1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabProDB.KEY_TIME) );
                        String date_time1 = date1 + "\n" +time1;
                        listItems.add(date_time1);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                  }
              }
              db.close();

         }catch (Exception e) {}

         arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems );

         date_time_ListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
         date_time_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


         date_time_ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AlertDialog.Builder ad  = new AlertDialog.Builder(History.this);
                    ad.setTitle("Delete?");
                    ad.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
                    final int positionToRemove = position;
                    String selectedFromList = (date_time_ListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                    String[] splitDateTime = selectedFromList.split("\n");
                    final String splitDate = splitDateTime[0];
                    Toast.makeText(History.this, splitDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String splitTime = splitDateTime[1];
                    ad.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                     ad.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            TabProDB db = new TabProDB(History.this);
                            try
                            {
                                db.open();
                                Cursor c = db.GetAllRecords();
                                if(c!=null)
                                {
                                    if(c.moveToFirst())
                                    {
                                        do
                                        {
                                            //search database to find a date that equals the date on the listview
                                            String findDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabProDB.KEY_DATE));
                                            if(splitDate.equalsIgnoreCase(findDate))
                                            {
                                                getdbID =c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TabProDB.KEY_ROWID));

                                                db.deleteRow(getdbID);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {

                                            }
                                        }while(c.moveToNext());

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){}
                            db.close();

                            listItems.remove(positionToRemove);
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    

                        }

                     });
                     ad.show();
                    return false;
                }

            });
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(History.this, Update.class);
    String str1[] = ((TextView) view).getText().toString().split("\n");
    String str2 = str1[0];
    String str3 = str1[1];

    i.putExtra("date", str2);
    i.putExtra("time", str3);
    i.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivity(i);

}

}
```

Comment: tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); remove this line and see

Comment: removing tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final Intent i = new Intent().setClass(TabBar.this,
            Recorder.class);
    TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Recoder");
    spec1.setContent(i);
    spec1.setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.title_card_post1),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1));


    final Intent i = new Intent().setClass(TabBar.this,
        History.class);
        TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("History");
    spec1.setContent(i);
    spec1.setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.title_card_post1),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1));

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
```

Try this code and let me know whether this works  for you because this  solution is working for me and one of my application does have it.

Comment: It seems not working either. I actually found something, but i'm very new to android programming, therefore i can't figure out how to apply this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467209/not-run-oncreate-on-tab-change-in-same-page-2nd-time