# Checkable drop-down list

Tags: android, tabs, swipe

When I swipe my tab I want it to alert multi select checkbox but not when application starts.I want it to alert when I am in second tab.How to achieve this functionality? I wrote the following code in the second Tab but the alert pops up at the time of application start.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
        final List<Integer> selectedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String[] itemList = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Multi Select");
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(itemList, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    selectedItems.add(which);
                }
            }
        }).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467209/not-run-oncreate-on-tab-change-in-same-page-2nd-time

Comment: @Dilip take a Adapter in listview then add your code in Adapter...

Comment: Why is my code not working? What concept I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by keeping a button in the fragment and showing the alert dialog on click.